# Perl IO::Socket::INET6::sockaddr_in6 redefined error

Tags: perl, cpan

We have a custom perl install (5.10.1) in /usr/share, and I tried to do a 'cpan -i' install of GeoIP2 [here](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/GeoIP2-0.0300/lib/GeoIP2.pm)

After doing this, it seemed to install a lot of dependencies I couldn't keep track of, and since I've been getting an error

```
Subroutine IO::Socket::INET6::sockaddr_in6 redefined at /usr/share/perl5/Exporter.pm line 67
```

On most scripts that we run that uses a 'use' command. I've been trying to nail down which module eventually calls that, but not succeeded as yet.

After some research, one suggestion was to comment out the following lines of

```
/usr/share/perl5/IO/Socket/INET6.pm # (version 2.56, think latest is 2.72)


###commented out the following
###use Socket6 (
###    qw(AI_PASSIVE inet_ntop inet_pton getaddrinfo
###    sockaddr_in6 unpack_sockaddr_in6_all pack_sockaddr_in6_all)
###);
```

This has stopped the errors from appearing on various scripts. Does anyone know if this is safe to do (ie will it cause further problems later), and is there a better way to go (ie is it possible to just update that module, I'm guessing that would cause problems and break other stuff?). What would be the best method of getting the module updated correctly ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a bug in IO::Socket::INET6 which was fixed in version 2.69 according to this [bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=72769):

> Subroutine main::sockaddr_in6 redefined at /usr/share/perl/5.14/Exporter.pm line 67.
>
> ...
>
> Should be fixed in 2.69.

You can update the module using cpan with the command `cpan IO::Socket::INET6` from the shell as root.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest is just to stop using `IO::Socket::INET6` at all. That was created a very long time ago, but a far better solution has been created using the core `Socket` module, being `IO::Socket::IP`. Furthermore, this latter module is now core also since the newly-released 5.20. it would be better to use that `IO::Socket::IP` as that is the new core-recommended way to achieve IPv4/IPv6 transparency from now on.